# Error function onclick jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a new javascript programmer, and i have this problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saluta is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):33)
```

on this code:

```
<button onclick="saluta()" id = "btn_sa">LOGIN</button>
```

and this is the function:

```
function saluta(){
            var username = document.getElementById("Name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var blocco = $("<div></br>Ciao </div>");
            if(password === "errata"){
                $(blocco).append(x);
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
                document.getElementById("btn_sa").disabled = true;
                }else{
                $(blocco).css({
                    "color" : "red"
                    "font-size" : "10px"                    
                    });
                $(blocco).append("Password Errata");
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
                }
            }
```

How can I resolve? I' ve found many people with my same problem in this forum but I can't resolve it!
p.s sorry if my english isn't very good

Comment: functions called from inline attributes must be defined globally, make sure your function is defined globally (eg not inside another function)

Comment: Try to avoid inline functions calling...since you use jQuery make your life easier... https://api.jquery.com/click/ Use jQuery selectors... and, not sure about your blocco var? What is desired behavior? What is x? Etc, etc...

Comment: Ok I've resolved using the .click function of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i resolved using the .click function of jquery:

```
$('#btn_sa').click(function saluta(){
            var username = document.getElementById("Name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var blocco = $("<div></br>Ciao </div>");
            console.log("funziona");
            if(password === "errata"){
                $(blocco).append(username);
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
                document.getElementById("btn_sa").disabled = true;
                }else{
                $(blocco).css({
                    "color" : "red",
                    "font-size" : "10px"                    
                    });
                $(blocco).append("Password Errata");
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an error in

```
"color" : "red"
```

is missing a `,` at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Your function should not be wrapped inside any another function.
Many tools and frameworks wrap your code. If you use JSFiddle, you should specify that you don't want your code to be wrapped[image]

For example see this code:

```
$(function(){
   function my_function(){

   }
})
```

In this case `my_function()` will be undefined, because it is wrapped inside outer function.

Comment: sorry I've not undersood, my function isn't wrapped in other function

Answer (score 0):

Well Emanuele, there might be something wrong. The best solution is to use jQuery **click** event as shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn_sa").click(function(){
            saluta();
        });
        var saluta = function(){
            var username = document.getElementById("Name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var blocco = $("<div></br>Ciao </div>");
            if(password === "errata"){
                $(blocco).append(x);
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
                document.getElementById("btn_sa").disabled = true;
                }else{
                $(blocco).css({
                    "color" : "red",
                    "font-size" : "10px"                    
                    });
                $(blocco).append("Password Errata");
                blocco.appendTo(document.body);
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
    Password: <input type="password" name="Name" id="Password">
    <button id = "btn_sa">LOGIN</button>
</body>
</html>
```